# Table getting deleted by Automatic Migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 4.3.1 and have automatic migrations enabled running with sql server 2008.  I've run across a strange problem where one of my tables is getting deleted - I even have AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed set to false.  My two tables are as follows:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public double Bpm { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; } //In Seconds
    public int? TimeSignature { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sample> Samples { get; set; } 
}
```

There's a foreign key on ArtistId.  I have both tables populated with data. Every so often, my application won't run because of a foreign key error.  I check the database and my Artist table is completely gone.  I look at my Samples table and the ArtistId column is removed and replaced with just an 'Artist' column (nvarchar) which previously wasn't there.  I know I'm not deleting data as I don't even have a delete method in my repositories.  If I remove all the data from the Samples table the Artist table appears and my application runs. Has anyone ran into this problem or have any idea why my setup may lead to this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is either something wrong in your setup or bug in migrations. In either case you will have to provide much more information (generally make the problem reproducible) before you get some answer.